# Heater not getting very hot

Tags: dodge, heater

I have a 1999 Dodge Dakota.  Early in the spring I had to have my heater core replaced.  Now it is starting to get cold outside.  When I run my heater it is getting luke warm at best.  Before the heater core was replaced it used to be a lot hotter.  What could have caused it to not kick out very much heat?

I regularly check my fluids and the coolant level is always right where it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You very likely have a bad thermostat.  Here are some similar questions that may provide some insight:

[Where'd my heat go?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3226/57)

[Why would my heater sometimes blow cold air?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/4589/57)

[Engine never warms up (actually: it cools down) at highway speeds](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1991/57)

In terms of your specific problem, I would check your engine temperature gauge: does the needle ever move up to its normal operating range?  Or does the coolant stay cold?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am sure I will fall into one of those categories.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the heater hoses and flush out the heater core using a garden hose. Be sure to flush it both ways. Test for leaks when done and add coolant as needed.